# Can we not enable ngix to act as reverse proxy and webserver, based on url?

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-14.04, node.js

This is my config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/example/public/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;

    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
```

**I want localhost/api to be redirected to nodejs server while rest should be handled by nginx.**

But when I check the `access.log`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2016:12:06:57 +0530] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 9 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
```

It means the nginx is trying to find api.html, but I want it to be redirected to locahost:3000

I checked online, and many config files for nginx had *only* acting as reverse proxy for node, or serving static content using file extensions like .jpg,.png etc

```
Can we not enable ngix to act as reverse proxy and webserver, based on url ?
```

> EDIT 1

If I server the nodejs server at / , and static files to some other path, then it works fine

Example

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/example/;

    location /public {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;

    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


}
```

I can browse the nodejs server at example.com/ and static files at example.com/public

**But I dont understand why is the problem in this simple configuration ( having static files in / and api server in example.com/api ).***

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: There are no updates in error logs

Comment: Basically, it is trying to find api.html for  /api.... but I want it to be redirected to node server. I found this stackoverflow question regarding nginx and apache [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031274/how-to-have-multiple-location-blocks-use-the-same-named-location) , but couldn't use it successfully in my context

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the trailing slash.

Comment: trailing slash in which line?

Comment: The only place you omitted a trailing slash, in the `location`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40097/discussion-between-h-s-and-michael-hampton).